# handling strings in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
s5=0
for phrase in root.findall('./PHRASE'):
    ens = {en.get('x'): en.text for en in phrase.findall('en')}
    if 'ORG' in ens and 'PERS' in ens:
      if (ens["ORG"] =="XYZ Corp" and ens["PERS"]=="John"):
          print("ORG is: {}, PERS is: {} /".format(ens["ORG"], ens["PERS"]))
          y="".join(phrase.itertext())   #print whats in between
          print(y)
          s5 = s5+1
print("occurrence of fifth seed : ",s5)
```

Here in each iteration, Y is printed, Y is the text in the XML document as long as I have 2 "en" tags, one ORG & 1 PERS.

**So the output is:**

```
John cofounder of XYZ Corp.
John works in XYZ Corp.
John named his company XYZ Corp.
```

I have been trying to save each sentence on its own so I can use it later.
For example I want to use the second sentence "John works in XYZ Corp" I don't know how to do that, I tried using the variable **Y** as 2d array but I failed.

Comment: What the problem to create a list and append results in `for` loop? `l = []` and then `l.append(y)` before `print` statement...

Answer (score 1):

As commented above:

```
    sentences = []
    y="".join(phrase.itertext())   #print whats in between
    print(y)
    sentences.append(y)
```

Then get the sentences back by indexing in to the 'sentences' list:

```
    print sentence[0] # first sentence
    print sentence[1] # second sentence, etc.
```